# how to import files from SharePoint team site to local machines?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

My client generating reports (excel files) monthly basis and they upload the files in the SharePoint document library. Again some reports are coming through the mail (outlook).

The requirement is we need to copy the excel reports (which are in document library and the files that are coming through mail) to the Landing zone(FTP Server) and we need to automate this process every month.

Which is the best way to achieve this ? please help me on this.Thank you..

Comment: You can use webclient service with powershell to download documents from Sharepoint document library. http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-webdav-webclient-service/

Comment: Thanks,but is it possible by powershell commaands???

Comment: Yes it is. Will share the code in some time

Comment: ok thanks.waiting fr ur valuable code...

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri = "https://intranet.company.com/departments/SampleSite/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/departments/SampleSite/Shared Documents/test.docx')/`$Value"
$FileBinary = $(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $cred -ContentType 'application/json;odata=verbose').Content
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('C:\tempfolder\test.docx',$FileBinary)
```

With this sample you can download a file and save it (it uses the SP REST API). This simple sample uses the credentials of the currently logged on user.

Edit : on request I've added a sample for SharePoint Online (you need the SP SDK for this because of the login flow). Code is not optimized though since this was one of my first samples. The problem is that you have to "hardcode" credentials. My solution for this within my company is encrypting the credentials with a certificate : I encrypt the credentials in a file using the public key of the service account that's running the script ; the service account uses the private key to decrypt it. Not ideal but safe enough for us.

```
$cred = Get-Credential # Get credentials

## Load the Assemblies
add-type -AssemblyName system.net.http
Add-type -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime\v4.0_16.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

# Put credentials in SPO credential object
$SPCred = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials]::new($cred.UserName,$cred.Password)
# Set the uri's
$uri = [uri]::new('https://YourTentant.sharepoint.com')
$fullUri = "https://YourTentant.sharepoint.com/sites/ApiTest/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/ApiTest/Shared Documents/Document.docx')/`$Value"
# Create HTTPClientHandler object and set the properties
$handler = [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler]::new()
$handler.Credentials = $SPCred
$handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies($uri,$SPCred.GetAuthenticationCookie($uri))

# Create the client and set the options
$Client = [System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::new($handler)
$Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
$Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add([System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue]::new('application/json'))
# Call the URL (async) and get the response
$Response = $Client.GetAsync($fullUri)
$data = $Response.Result

## now download the data as string (in the final version I'm going to call the ReadAsStream() method instead to get the binary file)
$a = $data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() 
$a.Result
```

Comment: This doesn't work in O365 (I had to write a new script for that since I can't use delegated credentials for that, I had to use the SharePoint SDK to get the login flow to work). I'll update the answer to include a working sample for SPO)